# SAS proc univariate for many variables by macro or array

Tags: sas

This should be an easy question, but I didn't figure out...
I want to get mean and median of many variables by `proc univariate` as below. It's really time consuming to manually add `M_` for mean and `MD_` for median to all variables. I am wondering if there any simple approach, such as array  to do so? Thanks a lot!

Code:

```
data old;
input year type A1 A2 A3 A4 A5;
datalines;
2000    1   1   2   3   4   5
2000    1   2   3   4   5   6
2000    2   3   4   5   6   7
2000    2   4   5   6   7   8
2001    1   5   6   7   8   9
2001    1   6   7   8   9   10
2001    1   7   8   9   10  11
2001    2   8   9   10  11  12
2001    2   9   10  11  12  13
2001    2   10  11  12  13  14
2002    1   11  12  13  14  15
2002    1   12  13  14  15  16
2002    1   13  14  15  16  17
2002    2   14  15  16  17  18
2002    2   15  16  17  18  19
2002    2   16  17  18  19  20
run;

proc univariate data=old noprint;
    var A1 A2 A3 A4 A5;
    by year type;
    output out=new
    mean=M_A1 M_A2 M_A3 M_A4 M_A5
    median=MD_A1 MD_A2 MD_A3 MD_A4 MD_A5;
run;
```

Expected demo Code:

```
%let varlist = A1 A2 A3 A4 A5; 
array vars (*) &varlist;
proc univariate data=old noprint;
    var &vars(*);
    by year type;
    output out=new
    mean=M_&vars(*)
    median=MD_&vars(*);
run;
```

correct code by using proc sql

```
%macro uni;
%let varlist='A1','A2','A3','A4','A5';
%let vars=A1 A2 A3 A4 A5;
proc sql;
select cats('M_',name) into :meannamelist separated by ' '
 from dictionary.columns
 where libname='WORK' and memname='OLD' and name in (&varlist);
select cats('MD_',name) into :mediannamelist separated by ' '
 from dictionary.columns
 where libname='WORK' and memname='OLD' and name in (&varlist);
quit;

proc univariate data=old;
    var &vars;
    by year type;
    output out=new
    mean=&meannamelist
    median=&mediannamelist;
run;
%mend uni;
options mprint;
%uni;
```

Comment: You can't use an array in PROC UNIVARIATE.  Arrays are (mostly) only Data step elements, or in data step-like environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to create these lists in PROC SQL.

```
%let varlist=A1,A2,A3,A4,A5;
proc sql;
select cats('M_',name) into :meannamelist separated by ' '
 from dictionary.columns
 where libname='WORK' and memname='OLD' and name in (&varlist);
select cats('MD_',name) into :mediannamelist separated by ' '
 from dictionary.columns
 where libname='WORK' and memname='OLD' and name in (&varlist);
quit;

proc univariate etc.;
mean &meannamelist;
median &mediannamelist;
run;
```

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at the edit? My guess is `A1` is not recognized as a variable

Comment: Ah, yes; you would need to quote the variables in the variable list, or use FIND or INDEX.

Comment: Adding quote works. but then sas did not recognize mean and median as function (log is listed in the edit)... sorry

Comment: `proc univariate etc;` is shorthand for 'whatever your proc univariate code is'.

Answer (score 1):

One way of completing your code is to loop through a list:

```
proc univariate data=old noprint;

  var

  %let varlist1 = A1 A2 A3 A4 A5;
  %let count_number1=1;
  %let value1=%scan(&varlist1.,&count_number1.); 
  %do %while(&value1. NE %str());

   &value1.

   %let count_number1=%eval(&count_number1.+1);
   %let value1=%scan(&varlist1.,&count_number1.);
  %end;
   ;

  by year type;
  output out=new
  mean=

   %let varlist2 = A1 A2 A3 A4 A5;
   %let count_number2=1;
   %let value2=%scan(&varlist2.,&count_number2.); 
    %do %while(&value2. NE %str());

       M_&value2. 

       %let count_number2=%eval(&count_number2.+1);
       %let value2=%scan(&varlist2.,&count_number2.);
     %end;
    ;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But I think the code doesn't work now although I made some changes...so may I ask a few questions? 1.is `&vars(*)` should be defined as array of varlist? 2.what does `%while(&elementValue. NE %str())` exactly mean?

Comment: The macro code loops through the list of variables in the varlist by incrementing a counter. It does this until it hits a blank - which is what '%while(&elementValue. NE %str())' is looking for

Comment: Thanks! This is what I thought, but I think the code is still buggy, below is the log errors, could you please advise how to fix it? (please see my edit in my original post)

Comment: Sorry, that code had a few bugs in it as I wrote it quickly. Have updated now - have replicated the loop for the var part, and also replaced &elementValue with the correct macro variable

Comment: Thank you for your updates!Unfortunately, I think 'var' and 'by' are treated as unrecognized variables now, which are indicated by error messages, so it still doesn't work...  
`ERROR: Variable VAR not found.
ERROR: Variable VAR not found.
ERROR: Variable VAR not found.
ERROR: Variable BY not found`

Comment: Sorry, var should have been outside the macro loop. Not having a good day!

Comment: This is a pretty good example of why macro loop programming is usually best avoided when possible (instead using tools like the SQL macro variable list, or data step programming) - it is very easy to write improperly and challenging to debug.

Comment: Thanks!! but still one more error as below, it seems there is missing ';'after variables,so "by" is treated as variable. But it still doesn't work even I added ";" which seems cut off the loop of 'var'. `MPRINT(UNI):   proc univariate data=old noprint;
'ERROR: Variable BY not found.
MPRINT(UNI):   var A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 by year type;
MPRINT(UNI):   output out=new mean= M_A1 M_A2 M_A3 M_A4 M_A5 run;`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `PROC MEANS` to obtain the needed stats, do that; it has an `autoname` option on the output statement that does approximately what you're asking for.  Both mean and median are available in `PROC MEANS`.

If not, you might look to `ods output` to simplify things.

Comment: Thank you! Proc means works for this case, but may I know how to do in proc univariate as I will need some other stats that proc means can't do.